# VBA create log file

Tags: vba, excel

Hello can you help me please with code in VBA ? I would like create a log file from text in cells ("C2" and "C3 " + date and time ) when I press button "zadat" Thank you

My code for implementation is:

**Module 1**

```
Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
Sub zadat()

Dim reg, check As String
Dim i, j, done As Integer
reg = Cells(2, 3).Value
check = Cells(4, 3).Value

If check = "True" Then

    i = 2
    j = 1
    done = 0
    Do While Sheets("data").Cells(i, j) <> ""
        If Sheets("data").Cells(i, j) = reg Then
            vytisteno = ZkontrolovatAVytiskoutSoubor()

            done = Sheets("data").Cells(i, j + 3)
            done = done + 1
            Sheets("data").Cells(i, j + 3) = done
            Exit Do
        End If
        i = i + 1

    Loop
Else
    MsgBox ("Opravit, špatný štítek!!!")
End If

Cells(3, 3) = ""

Cells(3, 3).Select
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = Cells(1, 1).row


End Sub
```

Module 2:

```
Option Explicit
Public Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" ( _
ByVal hwnd As Long, _
ByVal lpOperation As String, _
ByVal lpFile As String, _
ByVal lpParameters As String, _
ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long

Public Function PrintThisDoc(formname As Long, FileName As String)
On Error Resume Next
Dim x As Long
x = ShellExecute(formname, "Print", FileName, 0&, 0&, 3)
End Function

Public Function ZkontrolovatAVytiskoutSoubor() As Boolean
Dim printThis
Dim strDir As String
Dim strFile As String
strDir = "W:\Etikety\Štítky\Krabice\Testy"
strFile = Range("C2").Value & ".lbe"
If Not FileExists(strDir & "\" & strFile) Then
    MsgBox "soubor neexistuje!"
ZkontrolovatAVytiskoutSoubor = False
Else
printThis = PrintThisDoc(0, strDir & "\" & strFile)
ZkontrolovatAVytiskoutSoubor = True
End If
End Function

Private Function FileExists(fname) As Boolean
    'Returns TRUE if the file exists
    Dim x As String
    x = Dir(fname)
    If x <> "" Then FileExists = True _
       Else FileExists = False
End Function
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please let us know what's the issue with the code you shared? Any Errors? Or is the code not giving you expected results? Please specify a bit more clearly

Comment: I would like to create a code for loging cells C2 and C3 by pressing "zadat". (read text from cells C2 and C3, and write to the log file values in cells with date a time in front of this value from cells), I would implement these loging code so that functioned.

Comment: something like that (log file):                                                                      Date - Time - Value C2 - Value C3

Comment: So you need a function that will create a log file and write data into it copying from the cells you specified. Am i correct?

Comment: Yes correct :) would it be possible?

Comment: That's possible. Would you mind using a Text file as log file. If you don't try this http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/990/scripting-filesystemobject#t=20160819105053924843

Comment: I was thinking about using a text file so will be fine :)

Comment: Please go through the link i have shared. I hope that will help you build what you want :) If not please let me know i will try :)

Comment: Please can you help me with creating? I dont know how to implement the code so that code worked.

Comment: Do you want to create a new file every time, or append new data to an existing log file (which is typically what is meant by "log file")?

Comment: new data to an existing log file please :)

Comment: Here is my idea:   https://postimg.org/image/qbxxheah5/

Comment: @FiínekCahů, you can edit the output format according to your need

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this. Below code will create a new log file every time

```
Public Function LogDetails()
  Dim fso As Object
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

  Dim logFile As Object
  Dim logFilePath As String
  Dim logFileName As String

  'Replace 'TestLog' with your desired file name
  logFileName = "TestLog" & ".txt"
  myFilePath = "C:\Users\..\Desktop\" & logFileName 'Modify the path here

  If fso.FileExists(myFilePath) Then
    Set logFile = fso.OpenTextFile(myFilePath, 8)
  Else
    ' create the file instead
    Set logFile = fso.CreateTextFile(myFilePath, True)
  End If

  logFile.WriteLine "[" & Date & " " & Time & "] " & Worksheet("yoursheetnamehere").Cells(2, 3) & " " &  Worksheet("yoursheetnamehere").Cells(3, 3)

  logFile.Close ' close the file
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you, all is ok but this part of code nothing doing                     logFile.WriteLine "[" & Date & " " & Time & "] " & Cells(2, 3) & " " & Cells(3, 3)         my sheet has name "Kontrola" if help you and cells which will be write is C2 and C3 on this sheet.

Comment: @FiínekCahů You shouldn't expect a Stack Overflow answer to be 100% tailored to your exact spreadsheet. You should be able to modify this answer to match your needs. Stack Overflow isn't a free coding service that ships final products.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to use FSO, there is a simple solution using only VBA statements: [Open](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/office/gg264163.aspx), [Print #](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/office/gg264278.aspx) and [Close](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/office/gg264418.aspx):

```
Sub Log2File(Filename As String, Cell1, Cell2)
    Dim f As Integer
    f = FreeFile
    Open Filename For Append Access Write Lock Write As #f
    Print #f, Now, Cell1, Cell2
    Close #f
End Sub
```

I've put the filename and the cells refs as arguments of the sub for re-usability purpose. I also use default (local) formatting, but this can be easily changed.
Note that you don't have to check for existence of the file, it will be created if it doesn't exist.